# HttpGet working in SE application but not in Container

Tags: java

My test application works when running it from a SE application but when using the same code in a web based application it refuses to work.

example code:

```
SSLContextBuilder builder = new SSLContextBuilder();
        builder.loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(builder.build());

        HttpHost target = new HttpHost("test.test.com", 443, "https");
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("41.41.41.41", 3128, "http");

        final RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setConnectTimeout(5000)
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(5000)
                .setSocketTimeout(5000).setProxy(proxy)
                .build();

        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                .build();

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(validateUrl);
        httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + authenticationStringEncrypted);
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(target, httpGet);
```

In the web application it gets to this part:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                .build();
```

Then it stops, no exceptions are thrown and this block is surrounded with a try-catch, using multicatch to catch all exceptions.

```
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException | KeyStoreException | IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The web based application is deployed to glassfish 4.1.

Comment: Why don't you specify yet another generic exception i.e., Exception in your  catch block and see the cause. Also, check the log files in your glassfish containers to find any exceptions.

Comment: I have added a generic Exception and still no exception is thrown, not in my application logs nor the server.log in the domain itself